# Can't find module error when building docker for NodeJS app

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile

I wrote a DockerFile for a node application. This is the docker file:

```
FROM node:10.15.0

COPY frontend/  frontend/
WORKDIR frontend/ 
RUN npm install
RUN npm start
```

When I try to build this Dockerfile, I get this error: `ERROR in ./app/main.js Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './ResetPwd' in '/frontend/app'`

So I added `RUN ls` & `RUN ls /app` in Dockerfile. Both of the files are there! I'm not familiar with NodeJS and it's build process at all. Can anybody help me with this?

Point: I'm not sure if it helps or not, but I'm using Webpack too.

Comment: Can we see your package.json and your node.js version you are using locally? You may have some other build tools that are being ignored here

Comment: The node version was as same as the dockerFile node version. The problem was our front-end developer considered that node imports are case insensitive. That's why it couldn't find the modules. Module name was resetPass! Shimmy568

Comment: Awesome :)! Take a look at my answer there's some suggestions there to improve the dockerfile so it builds faster and stuff.

Comment: Sure :) Thanks for your help.  Shimmy568

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem was that our front-end developer considered that node imports are case insensitive and he was using windows. I tried to run Dockerfile on mac and that's why it couldn't find the modules. Module name was resetPass!

Comment: never expected this could be an issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

This question saved me!

hope this helps somebody else.

I have an angular app and I was trying to containerize it using docker.

I build the app on a windows machine. and I was trying to build it inside a linux container.

the app was building fine on my windows machine and failing with the following error in the docker environment:

```
    ERROR in folder1/folder2/name.component.ts: - error TS2307: Cannot find module '../../../folder1/File.name'.
    
    import { Interface1} from '../../../folder1/File.name';
```

Cannot find module '../../../node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts'.
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/observable';

it was driving me nuts.

I saw this question and at first did not think that it was what was going on. the next day I decided to build the same app in a linux environment just to make sure. Used WSL 2 and boom:

the real problem!

ERROR in  error TS1149: File name '/../../node_modules/rxjs/observable.d.ts' differs from already included file name '/../../node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts' **only in casing.**

6 import { Observable } from 'rxjs/observable';

**SO it was a casing issue.** I corrected the casing and it builds fine!

Answer (score 0):

I cant say if this will work for sure since I don't know if `npm start` actually triggers webpack, but if it doesn't you'll have to add an extra `RUN` line after the `COPY frontend /` line

There are a few issues here, try using this docker file instead

```
FROM node:10.15.0

# Copy dependency files and install packages
WORKDIR frontend
COPY frontend/package.* .
RUN npm install

# Copy src down and other stuff
COPY frontend /

# cd to the file with the package.json
WORKDIR /appDir/frontend

# Command that executes when container starts up
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Make sure that you also update your .dockerignore to include node_modules. You'll have to build and run the container with the following commands.

```
docker build -t frontendApp .
docker run -p 8080:8080 frontendApp
```

The -p and 8080:8080 have to do with exposing internal ports to the outside world so you can view it in a browser, just change it to whatever port web pack is using to display your stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I had to rebuild the disruptive package, like in [this issue for node-sass](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/2536)

The command would be `npm rebuild <package-name>`

For me, this was `npm rebuild node-sass`